# Connection not cleaned up if client failure occurs abruptly without closing the resources

Tags: jboss, jms, jmx, hornetq

I am using hornetq-2.2.14 Final and configured connection-ttl in hornetq-jms.xml is 60000ms . I have a publisher program which sends messages to a topic and a Consumer program which consumes messages from the topic. My consumer program exited abruptly without closing the resources. I waited 1 minute since the ttl is 60000ms,but server not clearing up the resources even after one minute. Any one can help me out to resolve this issue, if this is a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can take as 2X TTL depending on how it happened. we recently had a fix on master to make sure it is always close to the TTL configured.

Comment: Hi Clebert, still not working ..I think this is a bug in 2.2.14 Final.

Comment: We definitely test TTL, you need to provide a failing test and prove it's a bug then